# MERN on Heroku does not work across browsers

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, deployment, mern

I developed MERN app with MLab, React, Redux. **Works fine in dev**.
I deployed in Heroku and  **works fine in the Chrome that I used for developing** (with React, Redux attachments).

**Issue**: It shows up blank in any other browser in my machine, including in chrome in any other machines. I looked in the net and per a solution in this forum, I did the following on the server.js (or app.js). That is, in my own chrome this URL (https://servicexpoc.herokuapp.com/) works fine but in any other it is a blank page.

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
        // app.use(express.static('client/build')); returns blank page
        // Changed to ...
        app.use('/static', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client/build')));
        app.get('*', (req, res) => {
        res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'client', 'build', 'index.html'));
      });
    }
```

Did the traditional ... git stuff (git add, commit) then check the  remote connect to Heroku and did the 'git push heroku master' . Everything went fine ... the server is up and sunning. And once again, it shows up in my chrome and works like a charm ... BUT Nowhere else.

Following  is my server side package.json:

```
    {
      "name": "appname",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "description": "Developer Connection social media",
      "main": "server.js",
      "scripts": {
      "client-install": "npm install --prefix client",
      "start": "node server.js",
      "server": "nodemon server.js",
      "client": "npm start -prefix client",
      "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\"",
      "heroku-postbuild": "NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix 
 client && npm run build --prefix client"
  },
      "author": "Jit <sarbojit.project@gmail.com>",
      "license": "ISC",
      "dependencies": {
      "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
      "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
      "concurrently": "^3.6.0",
      "express": "^4.16.3",
      "gravatar": "^1.6.0",
      "jsonwebtoken": "^8.3.0",
      "mongoose": "^5.1.5",
      "passport": "^0.4.0",
      "passport-jwt": "^4.0.0",
      "validator": "^10.3.0"
     }
}
```

Following is  the client side package.json

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
  "axios": "^0.18.0",
  "classnames": "^2.2.6",
  "jwt-decode": "^2.2.0",
  "moment": "^2.22.2",
  "react": "^16.4.1",
  "react-dom": "^16.4.1",
  "react-moment": "^0.7.7",
  "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
  "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
  "react-scripts": "1.1.4",
  "redux": "^4.0.0",
  "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
 },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
 },
 "proxy": "http://localhost:5000"
}
```

My directory structure:

```
appName
  client
    public 
      ... index.html (that is the root of react)
    src
      ... this has all the react code
  package.json (client side)
....... SERVER SIDE  
server.js
models  
   ... all models here
routers
   ... all routers here
validations
   ... all validations here
package.json   (SERVER SIDE)
.gitignore
```

Trying to follow directives as on:
https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

ANY HELP ...

Comment: I get a syntax error in the console when trying to load your app. Clear your  cache on your dev machine and see if it still works correctly. Then figure out what that syntax error is.

Answer (score 0):

In order for Heroku to render, and if you happen to have annexed REDUX DEVTOOLS in your chrome for development, do the following:

const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  initialState,
  compose(
    applyMiddleware(...middleware),
    //window.**REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION** && window.**REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION**()
    // Check if the next thig works
    window.**REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION**
      ? window.**REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION**()
      : f => f
  )
);

Initially, I forced the chrome to add the DEVTOOL (as above, now commented replaced by ternary). Heroku, while building, was not ignoring that and neither did it create an error or even warning. It just did not render (blank). In the above scenario, this would render your pages.